# How is Neo4J intended to fit into a Data Scientists work flow?

Tags: python, neo4j, data-science

For a Data Scientist that does network analysis mostly in Python, pulling data from a relational database, how is Neo4J intended to change my workflow? Is it mostly intended to efficiently query data (replace the relational database) or also data exploration?

Answer (score 2):

The question is a little open.
Will you as a Data Scientist benefit from using Neo4J? Depends...

1. Does your organization provide the neo4j instance? if so, thats a bonus if it doesnt provide alternatives such as Spark/JanusGraph etc
2. Is the data you are going to work on already in an existing neo4j or are you planning to put it there 'in order to benefit from neo4j'?

If its already there and the dataset is large, you most surely will benefit from its UI to help you explore the data. you can use its built in implementations of graph algorithms instead of loading the data locally and running your own versions of page-rank which will be un-optimized or not run at all due to memory limitations in your dev machine.

The data structure in neo4j helps you run very connected queries easily which otherwise would have resulted in multiple unpleasant joins which you will work very hard in order to implement (even if using a relational db)

If the answer was no, the data isnt already there, you have alternatives which would work, maybe even better, spark for one which has its own graph api to perform graph algros on your dataframes.
If your organization has a managed spark, even better.

So in short, if the data is already there, it could save you a lot of time and effort. if its not already there, using spark, even locally if the data isnt too big, might be easier.

Comment: This is extremely useful. The data is very large, but we have no enterprise instance of Neo4j, I was thinking it may be useful to get the free local version of neo4j, but sounds like that would not benefit me much.

I think your bit about connected queries is very interesting. I find it very challenging in the current state to query on a node + 2-3 hops. With the current relational DB, this ends up being a lot of queries, which are slow. It sounds like this is where there would be the major efficiency gains from Neo4j (as a replacement to the relational data store)? Does this sound right?

Comment: yes that sounds about right, connected queries and graph algorithms are where it shines.
It would probably reduce these multi-hop joins from seconds to milliseconds using Neo4J. but remember you will still need to put the data into Neo4J, and if the data is large, you might want the Neo4J isntance to run on a different, strong, machine.

You also have the learning curve of Cypher, Neo4J query language and getting the data into Neo, maybe even using Neo4J's Bolt api. 
Also remodeling the data in a graph-oriented way.

I would look at Spark GraphX examples just to see what sounds better